# jQuery method slideToggle() and resize() not working well

Tags: jquery

I have created a table with DIV-s in desktop mode (>767px) and a accordions system on mobile mode (<768px). I used a (document).ready with 2 IF-s and (window).resize with the same IF-s, in this way even if the user changes the width of his browser the view changes automatically.

Everything is working good, but when you change from first time desktop mode into mobile mode the accordions system is a little messy. Am i doing something wrong?

Full [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/joankucuqi/mfucv9vm/)

JS code:

```
function accordion() {
  if (jQuery(window).width() < 768) {
    $('.content_1').hide();
    $('.child_1_1').hide();
    $('.child_1_2').hide();
    $('.child_1_3').hide();
    $('.parent_1 .title').click(function() {
      $('.content_1').slideToggle("fast");
      $('.child_1_1').slideToggle("fast");
      $('.child_1_2').slideToggle("fast");
      $('.child_1_3').slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $('.content_1_1').hide();
    $('.child_1_1 .title').click(function() {
      $('.content_1_1').slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $('.content_1_2').hide();
    $('.child_1_2 .title').click(function() {
      $('.content_1_2').slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $('.content_1_3').hide();
    $('.child_1_3 .title').click(function() {
      $('.content_1_3').slideToggle("fast");
    });
  }

  else if (jQuery(window).width() > 767) {
    $('.content_1').show();
    $('.child_1_1').show();
    $('.child_1_2').show();
    $('.child_1_3').show();
    $('.content_1_1').show();
    $('.content_1_2').show();
    $('.content_1_3').show();
    $('.parent_1 .title').off();
    $('.child_1_1 .title').off();
    $('.child_1_2 .title').off();
    $('.child_1_3 .title').off();
    $('.front').hide();
  }
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  accordion();
});

$( window ).resize(function() {
  accordion();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code to make it work on resize http://jsfiddle.net/mfucv9vm/16/

```
function accordion() {
    if (jQuery(window).width() < 768) {
        $('.content_1, .child_1_1, .child_1_2, .child_1_3, .content_1_1, .content_1_2, .content_1_3').hide();       

    } else if (jQuery(window).width() > 767) {
        $('.content_1, .child_1_1, .child_1_2, .child_1_3, .content_1_1, .content_1_2, .content_1_3').show();       
        $('.front').hide();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    accordion();
    $('.parent_1 .title').on('click', function () {
        if (jQuery(window).width() < 767) {
            $('.content_1').stop().slideToggle("fast");
            $('.child_1_1').stop().slideToggle("fast");
            $('.child_1_2').stop().slideToggle("fast");
            $('.child_1_3').stop().slideToggle("fast");
        }
    });

    $('.child_1_1 .title').on('click', function () {
        if (jQuery(window).width() < 767) {
            $('.content_1_1').stop().slideToggle("fast");
        }
    });

    $('.child_1_2 .title').on('click', function () {
        if (jQuery(window).width() < 767) {
            $('.content_1_2').stop().slideToggle("fast");
        }
    });

    $('.child_1_3 .title').on('click', function () {
        if (jQuery(window).width() < 767) {
            $('.content_1_3').stop().slideToggle("fast");
        }
    });
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    $('.content_1, .child_1_1, .child_1_2, .child_1_3, .content_1_1, .content_1_2, .content_1_3').hide();       

    accordion();
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Bojan Petkovski , but even in the updated code is the same error.. Look, open the result window in JSFiddler in the desktop mode, refrash the page, now make the result window smaller to view the mobile view.. try it in this way and you will show the error that i'm talking about..

Comment: Hard to explain, but i can tell that is occurring a strange animation, like a bounce..

Comment: I have updated the answer, check if now the bouncing happens :)

Comment: In Firefox works fine.. i think is a Chrome bug.. :/
Thank you for your help :)